# Flutter timer stops when screen is locked

Tags: flutter, timer, locking, countdown, unlock

I have a Flutter application that has a timer using it to implement countdown. When the screen is locked by itself it when it is locked by itself, the timer stops until I unlock the device again. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: give a try with background service

Comment: tried it but the same issue